# GMSMapview Handling Rotation and Car Rotation ios

Tags: ios, google-maps, rotation, cllocationmanager

I'm using google maps. Im getting user current location with course(angle) from cllocationmanger. After getting the location I'm adding to the GMSMapview.

Now my problem is car movement and map rotation. I want my map view to behave like googlemaps navigation. What I'm doing is after getting course of location I'm assigning it bearing of GMSMapview  and not rorating the car.

But in navigation app they are rotating navigation arrow and also the map changing to north direction when ever there is a turn(left or right).

To achieve that do I need use both course and heading of CLLocationmanager.

here is my code. when ever there is a chnage in location im calling this method.

```
func ShowcurrentMarker()
{
    currentlocationCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(LatestLocation.coordinate.latitude, LatestLocation.coordinate.longitude)

    if(CurrentLocationMarker == nil)
    {

        CurrentLocationMarker = GMSMarker(position:currentlocationCoordinate)
        CurrentLocationMarker.map = self.mapView
        CurrentLocationMarker.icon = UIImage.init(named:"car_icon")
        self.mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: LatestLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: LatestLocation.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 18, bearing: CLLocationDirection.abs(LatestLocation.course), viewingAngle: 65)
    }
    else
    {
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(2)
        CurrentLocationMarker.position = currentlocationCoordinate            
        self.mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: LatestLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: LatestLocation.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 18, bearing: CLLocationDirection.abs(LatestLocation.course), viewingAngle: 65)


        CATransaction.commit()

    }
}
```

Please help me..

Thank you...